# How to execute custom action before installing files when using VS's Setup Project?

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have a simple VS setup project. On the first screen user inputs database name and credentials to access it. Then user clicks 'Next' button and files are copied.
I would like to add one check which should be executed after user typed database name and credentials, but before copying files. This check should hit the database and verify some info. And depending on the result of this check installation will be continued or interrupted.

How could i do it? Is it possible to do it using VS setup project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that it is impossible to execute custom action before installing files using VS's setup project. This is because VS's setup project copies files at first and after that executes custom actions. This is by design.
That's why I decided to create a small winforms application with setup's interface and required behavior.