# Execute an script/application after installing (using VS Setup Project)

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment

I need to execute a *Console Application* script after installing my application. Depending on the Windows version, it adds some data to the Registry.

**How can I do this using a Visual Studio Setup Project?**

**Note:**
I'm saying **after** because I read in [How to execute custom action before installing files when using VS's Setup Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651583/how-to-execute-custom-action-before-installing-files-when-using-vss-setup-projec) that it isn't possible to do it before, but it doesn't really matter in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the custom action under Install node. I don't really understand what you mean by "console application script", but if you mean a BAT file you can write a custom EXE which launches it through ShellExecute.

If you are using a DLL, make sure that "InstallerClass" custom action property is set correctly:

- *False* for Win32 DLLs
- *True* for .NET Installer Class actions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was doing, but after doing this is necessary to set the *InstallerClass* property to *False* ;) Just edit your answer to add it and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87ad51/3/